# An expression for the $k$-th derivative of $f(x)=x^n\exp(-x)$

Tags: differential-calculus

Is there a finite  expression for $k$-th derivative of
\begin{align}
f(x)={x^n}{e^{ - x}}
\end{align}

Comment: Have you tried differentiating a number of times, then guessing the pattern: e.g.,  $f^{(n)} = P_n (x)e^{-x}$, and working out the recursive condition on the polynomials $P_n$ (which depend on $N$ as well)?

Comment: This is not research level, so it doesn't belong at MO.  It could probably do well at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com), although (a) I'd be surprised if it's not there already, and (b) as @DavidHandelman [says](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368706/an-expression-for-the-k-th-derivative-of-fx-xn-exp-x#comment930390_368706), it's something for which you can at least gather experimental data (and show that you have done so before asking others to do it).

Comment: Have u tried to use [Leibniz's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule)? am affraid that is not a question for MO website ,MO website is not for standard questions but for question in high level of research

Answer (score 1):

The command of Maple

```
diff(x^n*exp(-x), x $ k);
```

produces $$\sum _{k_1=0}^{k}{k\choose {k_1}}{\it pochhammer} \left( n
-{k_1}+1,{k_1} \right) {x}^{n-{k_1}}{{\rm e}^{-x}}
\left( -1 \right) ^{k-{k_1}}
$$
and the code of Mathematica

```
D[x^n*Exp[-x], {x, k}]
```

performs $$e^{-x} k! \binom{n}{k} x^{n-k} \, _1F_1(-k;-k+n+1;x) .$$

Comment: Just use Leibniz's formula 
$(fg)^{(k)}= \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i} f^{(i)} g^{(k-i)}$.

Comment: @Ira Gessel: Disagreed since CASes simplify it, e.g. for $k=5$ we have $${{\rm e}^{-x}} \left(  \left( {n}^{5}-10\,{n}^{4}+35\,{n}^{3}-50\,{n}^
{2}+24\,n \right) {x}^{n-5}+ \left( -5\,{n}^{4}+30\,{n}^{3}-55\,{n}^{2
}+30\,n \right) {x}^{n-4}+ \left( 10\,{n}^{3}-30\,{n}^{2}+20\,n
 \right) {x}^{n-3}+ \left( -10\,{n}^{2}+10\,n \right) {x}^{n-2}+5\,{x}
^{n-1}n-{x}^{n} \right)
 .$$

Comment: With what are you [disagreeing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368706/an-expression-for-the-k-th-derivative-of-fx-xn-exp-x#comment930398_368707)?  Your first formula, from Maple, is literally just @IraGessel's [suggestion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/368706/an-expression-for-the-k-th-derivative-of-fx-xn-exp-x#comment930395_368707).

Comment: @LSpice, I repeat that both CASes may find simplified expressions for concrete values of $k$. Those expressions are too long to do it by hand.